# Where is docker volume stored in the host computer for docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Consider the following `docker-compose` file

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - ./vol_folder:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Here is my command history on my `mac`

```
docker-compose up

psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U postgres

create table test (my_id bigserial primary key);
INSERT INTO test (my_id) values (1);
SELECT * FROM test;

\q
```

Originally I thought the above commands will cause a `.sql` file to be created in `./vol_folder` of the host computer. But I don't see any `.sql` file in `./vol_folder` rather just an empty `data` directory in `./vol_folder`

Furthermore if I `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` again I can see my data in the database is now gone.

I suspected that when I created the data when the image is running, the data is not stored back to `./vol_folder` thus when I reboot, there is nothing to mount from the host.

So I guess my question is where is the volume stored in my host computer? Is docker volume only one way (eg. host data to container) not two way?

Comment: `.` is the current directory, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I replaced `.` with the full path, the same problem still occurs

Answer (score 11):

The volumes will normally be stored somewhere in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`

To find out more, try the following commands

```
docker volume ls
docker volume inspect <volume identifier>
```

See also: https://www.linux.com/learn/docker-volumes-and-networks-compose

Answer (score 3):

On mac

```sh
docker volume ls  
docker volume inspect <volume identifier>
```

Will give you the mount point within the Docker virtual filesystem, not on your mac filesystem.

Docker is not natively compatible with macOS, so Hyperkit is used to run a virtual image. Its virtual image data is located in:

`~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0`

You can investigate your Docker root directory by creating a shell in the virtual environment:

```sh
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume identifier>/_data
ls
```

You can kill this session by pressing Ctrl+a, followed by pressing k and y.

Credit to: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/